# how to read a string and then save it to an array in java

Tags: java

I want to read a string and then put it in the first position of a string array in java

```
for (int i=1;i<100;i++) {

            System.out.print("Enter a string : ");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in);

            String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("String read from console is : \n"+inputString);
            inputString = thisIsAStringArray[];
}
```

Comment: `thisIsAStringArray[0] = inputString` ? If you really do not know how to do assignments or how to address array positions, then you should go and read some very basic Java books and/or tutorials.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes you are right. I am new to Java and i have stuck. I tried it what you told me but it didnt work. The error says: non-static variable thisIsAStringArray cannot be referenced from a static context. Also i have declarate the variable like this: private String[]  thisIsAStringArray = new String[]; 
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a string should be done with while loop but what you want to do is done here. This solution saves strings to only first index.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
       String [] thisIsAStringArray = new String[20]; //Only 20 string can be saved.
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int i = 0; i < 100;i++) {
        thisIsAStringArray[0] = in.nextLine(); ///Save element to first position.
        System.out.println("String entered is " + thisIsAStringArray[0]); //Get the element from the first position.
       }

}
```

This solution does not save to first position but to every index of the array.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        String [] thisIsAStringArray = new String[20]; //Only 20 string can be saved.
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < thisIsAStringArray.length;i++) {
            thisIsAStringArray[i] = in.nextLine(); ///Save element to first position.
            System.out.println("String entered is " + thisIsAStringArray[i]); //Get the element from the first position.
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you create a String list and assign the String in the head of the String array. ANd you get the index of the head of the array with a helper function.

```
String[] thisIsAStringArray = new String[10];
for (int i=1;1<100;i++) {

            System.out.print("Enter a string : ");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in);

            String inputString = scanner.nextLine(); // READ IN THE STRING 
            System.out.println("String read from console is : \n"+inputString);
            int pos= firstNonullPosition(thisIsAStringArray);
            if(pos!=-1)
                thisIsAStringArray[]=inputString; 
            else
                System.out.println("Array is full!");
            System.out.println("The String at the position 0 of the String array thiIsAStringArray is:" +thisIsAStringArray[0]);


}

public static int firstNonullPosition(String[] a)
{
    int index=0;
    while(a[index]!= null)
    {  
         index++;
         if (index > a.length)
             return -1;
    }
    return index;

}
```